# Java // No match with RegExp and square brackets

Tags: java, regex, square-bracket

I have a string like

```
Berlin -> Munich [label="590"]
```

and now I'm searching a regular expression in Java that checks if a given line (like above) is valid or not.
Currently, my RegExp looks like `\\w\\s*->\\s*\\w\\s*\\[label=\"\\d\"\\]"`
However, it doesn't work and I've found out that `\\w\\s*->\\s*\\w\\s*` still works but when adding `\\[` it can't find the occurence `(\\w\\s*->\\s*\\w\\s*\\[)`.
What I also found out is that when `'->'` is removed it works `(\\w\\s*\\s*\\w\\s*\\[)`

Is the arrow the problem? Can hardly imagine that.
I really need some help on this.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the correct regular expression:

```
"\\w+\\s*->\\s*\\w+\\s*\\[label=\"\\d+\"\\]"
```

What you report about matches and non-matches of partial regular expressions is very unlikely, not possible with the Berlin/Munich string.

Also, if you are really into German city names, you might have to consider names like `Castrop-Rauxel` (which some wit has called the Latin name of `Wanne-Eickel` ;-) )

Comment: Ok, so the + after \\w did the trick. But what do I need them for? If I'm not mistaken + means "occurs one or several times" and just \\w "one time". But the words in the example above consist of just one word, so why doesn't \\w work?

Comment: @Andy \w is a word character, not a whole word

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
 String message = "Berlin -> Munich [label=\"590\"]";
 Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\w+\\s*->\\s*\\w+\\s*\\[label=\"\\d+\"\\]");
 Matcher matcher = p.matcher(message);
 while(matcher.find()) {
      System.out.println(matcher.group());
 }
```

You need to much more than one token of characters and numbers.

Comment: Why the while loop? It will parse some funny-looking strings in `message`. A single test with `matcher.matches()` should be all that's required.

Comment: @laune this is a testing code, to make sure your regular expression is not matching those funny groups, not that it will do in this case.